# Why is React state not updated inside functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that renders a table with objects. This component shows a button that, when pressed, sends the parent a specific object. The parent must set it in the state to display some graphical stuff. The rendering is working correctly, what I don't understand is why I am getting an outdated value after setting the state correctly.
**It's not a race condition**, React is simply ignoring the updated value of a variable, even when it re-renders the component correctly.

A minimal example:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { SomeComponent } from "./SomeComponent";

export default function App() {
  const [currentID, setCurrentID] = useState(null);

  function getData() {
    console.log("Getting data of: ", currentID); // PROBLEM: this is null
  }

  function setAndRetrieveData(value) {
    setCurrentID(value);

    // Just to show the problem and discard race conditions.
    setTimeout(() => {
      getData();
    }, 1500);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Current ID: {currentID}</h1> {/* This works fine */}
      <SomeComponent getInfoFor={setAndRetrieveData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SomeComponent:**

```js
export function SomeComponent(props) {
  const randomID = 45;

  return <button onClick={() => props.getInfoFor(randomID)}>Get info</button>;
}
```

[image: Edit react update state]

Even with solutions like [useStateCallback](https://github.com/acjr1910/useStateCallback) the problem persists.

Is there a way to do this without having to use the awful `useEffect` which is not clear when reading the code? Because the logic of the system is "when this button is pressed, make a request to obtain the information", using the hook `useEffect` the logic becomes "when the value of `currentID` changes make a request", if at some point I want to change the state of that variable and perform another action that is not to obtain the data from the server then I will be in trouble.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `setTimeout` is a `closure`, therefore, when `setTimeout` is scheduled it uses the value at that exact moment in time, which is the initial value 

To solve this, use the `useRef` Hook:

Comment: you can refer this discussion and for this solution of `useref ` https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I'll read it carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an issue with the way Javascript closures work.

When you execute a function, it gets bundled with all the data that pertains to it and then gets executed.

The issue is that you call this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
      getData();
    }, 1500);
```

inside `setAndRetrieveData(value)`.

Even though it's inside a setTimeout, the getData() function has been bundled with the information it needs (`currentID`) at that point in time, not when it actually runs. So it gets bundled with the currentId before the state update takes place

Unfortunately, I would recommend using useEffect. This is the best way to ensure you avoid issues like this and any potential race conditions. Hopefully someone else can provide a different approach!

Comment: Effectively, that's the problem. I fixed it by verifying the state of `currentID` and a lot of more variables in a `useEffect` callback. Now my code it's dirtier and less maintainable, but the bug disappeared. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

when `setAndRetrieveData` is called it sets a state that leads to the component being rerendered to reflect the new state. When the timeout finishes The function `getData` was created in the previous render. And thus only has access to the state variable from the previous render. That now is undefined.

what you could try is using a `useEffect` hook that that listens to changes of
currentID.

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
         // Do something with the updated value
      },1000);
      return () => {
          // if the data updates prematurely 
          // we cancel the timeout and start a new one
          clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }
   },[currentID])
```

Comment: I'll definitely go back to React classes, `useEffect` fixed the problem, but It makes the code a lot more verbose and unclear. Thank you very much for your answer!